# how to hide footer when i scroll the page and appears when i stop in ionic 2

Tags: scroll, ionic2, hide, footer

I want to hide the footer when user scroll the page up or down. and it again appears when it stops scrolling in ionic2. I did not find the correct answer anywhere. My code is as below

```
<ion-content>
 <ion-list>
 <ion-item *ngFor=" let grocery of groceries">
    {{grocery}}
 </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer>What is the time?</ion-footer>
```

```
export class HomePage {
 groceries:any;
 products:any;
 demos:any;
 content:any
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  this.groceries = [
           'Bread',
           'Milk',
           'Cheese',
           'Snacks',
           'Apples',
           'Bananas',
           'Peanut Butter',
           'Chocolate',
           'Avocada',
           'Vegemite',
           'Muffins',
           'Paper towels',
          ];
    }
 }
```

Comment: A footer by definition sticks at the bottom.. If you want it to scroll.. why not just set the part in content?

Comment: You could set an boolean variable to a `*ngIf` and use the `Content` component's ionScrollStart and ionScrollEnd to set this variable as true or false and hide the footer. Sorry i can't build a code for you now, but see here https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/

Comment: Ref : https://medium.com/@gregor.srdic/ionic3-hidding-header-on-footer-on-content-scroll-15ab95b05dc5

Answer (score -1):

A footer by definition sticks at the bottom. and I do not think you can change it.I have encountered the same problem.I solved the problem like this.And the worked for me

**sample**

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-list>
       <ion-item *ngFor=" let grocery of groceries">
           {{grocery}}
       </ion-item>
     </ion-list>

     <ion-row>
       <ion-col>
         What is the time?
       </ion-col>
     </ion-row>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: This is not what op wants. He want to hide the footer as the page scrolls, not scroll the footer with the page,

Comment: I know what you want.But the footer will be fixed at the bottom.And I think it will be difficult to do what you want.Mine was just a suggestion